# Assigning variable length list data (from csv) to an 'indicator_column' feature

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a feature as follows:

```
tf.feature_column.indicator_column(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_file(...))
```

Corresponding `'vocabulary_file'` contains integer values as follows:

10

20

32

44

5

1212

...

Consider such training examples:

Jack, M, 22, **"[10, 20]"**, 2.33, 1

Sara, F, 24, **"[32, 44, 5, 1212]"**, 5.6, -1

Each training example has a variable length list data like **[10, 20]** or **[32, 44, 5, 1212]**

Now, I want to capture this data from csv file into the `'indicator_column'` feature and then feed the *multi-hot representation* (result) to a deep model.
The `decode_csv` function only support `float32`, `float64`, `int32`, `int64`, `string` and I have issue for `'list'` type data in csv.

> System information:

OS Platform: Win8,
TensorFlow installed from: binary,
TensorFlow version: 1.5,
Python version: 3.6,
Bazel version: None,
CUDA/cuDNN version: None,
GPU model and memory: GPU> None | CPU> AMD(Phenom II x4),

Exact command to reproduce is clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here. First, official CSV format does not have any concept of recursion - having an individual cell actually be multiple values to be parsed.

You could achieve what you wanted if the size of the internal list was constant by calling `decode_csv` twice (ipython REPL using eager execution):

```
In [21]: a, b, c = tf.decode_csv(tf.constant('"Jack","10, 20",1'), ["", "", 0])

In [22]: tf.decode_csv(b, [0, 0])
Out[22]: 
[<tf.Tensor: id=113, shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=10>,
 <tf.Tensor: id=114, shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=20>]
```

However, official CSV format does not support variable length data either - each row is supposed to have the same number of fields/columns.

Given all these limitations of CSV, I would suggest the following alternative approach (assuming you want to stay in text - if not, you can encode your data in TFRecord):

- Use tf.data API.
- Use TextLineDataset to read lines from your files. See https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#consuming_text_data
- Write your own line parsing function in python and call it using the `tf.py_func`. See https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#applying_arbitrary_python_logic_with_tfpy_func.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer` and `tf.feature_column.indicator_column` like this :

```
mlb = sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer()
mlb.fit([item.split(",") for item in user_df[column]])
multi_hot_column_dict[column] = tf.feature_column.indicator_column(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(column, mlb.classes_))
```